# Simple set theory proving problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

this is my first time asking a question on a website so here goes.

I got this question from discrete maths class in set theory i know it is simple but please take in mind that i am studying everything alone because of the virus and it is my first semester(and i have asked friends for help with no success).
we need to prove that the left side is equal to the right side 
(A ∪ B) \ (C\B)=B ∪ (A\C)

i used venn diagram and they are truly equal to check but other than that i did not manage to actually prove it
as venn's diagram is not a proof

thank you , stay safe everyone and sorry again for the simple question!

Comment: Hi, welcome.  No question is too simple, as long as it's well-asked.  It helps to explain what you have tried (in your case, Venn diagram).

Comment: Welcome! Perhaps try and take an arbitrary element of the LHS, say $x$, and try to show that it must be in the RHS. Do the same going the other way and you'll have proved that each sides are subsets of eachother and so must be the same set!

Comment: On the left side, if $x \in (A\cup B)\setminus(C\setminus B),$ then $x \in A\cup B$ and $x\notin C\setminus B$.  So $(x\in A \lor x \in B) \land \lnot (x \in C \land x\notin B)$...  Continue.  This is what iCaird is suggesting, sometimes called "element chasing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below an attempt at proving the --> implication . The reverse implication is still to be proved.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the help , after the explanation the right side was easy

Comment: Visit [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a primer on how to type with MathJax and $\LaTeX$.  There is no reason to be posting screenshots of a word document rather than typing the math directly into this site.  Also, the reference to Covid19 is unnecessary and distracts from the mathematics.  It is far more traditional to refer to the arbitrary element as $x$ or similar.